# No mobile data with CM13

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-data

I have flashed CM13 onto my Samsung Galaxy S3, and since then, mobile data does not work. I am logged in into the network and I can make calls and receive SMS, so the IMEI / EFS data is still there and working. Connecting to the mobile network works, too, the "mobile data" button is enabled.

No matter which app I try to use, none of them can connect to the internet with mobile data. I only get error messages. However, resetting the mobile data statistics and then trying again still gives me error messages, but a few kilobytes of data usage appear in the statistics.

I already tried: 
- Wipe Cache
- Re-flash CM13
- Restart phone a dozen times
- Enable and disable Airplane Mode a dozen times
- Deleting the APN and re-entering the exact information I got from my provider
- Completely disable and uninstall AFWall+
- Disable any "data restriction" / security / privacy settings I could find that could possibly cause this

What else could be the problem? Why does my mobile data not work?

Comment: i followed the steps on this youtube video... it worked for me after trying many alternatives.....hope it works for u guys as well.........https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_Cy0oyN1Pg

Answer (score 1):

If someone still has no mobile data, delete all APNs except the one you need. That fixed it for me after a lot of time of investigation﻿

Comment: Last night I installed cm13 ROM and had the same problem
And I read the above about deleting APN which works fine thanks a lot #copa07 you saved my time thank you so much..
Hats off...

Comment: @Siije you are very welcome, thanks a lot for the feedback (don't forget to vote, will help others to see it)

Answer (score 0):

My phone is LG G3 (D855) with xosp 6.0.1 (Based on cyanogenmod)
I fix it
-Go to google play store
- Type apn 
- Download apn settings
- Download Link2Sd
- Run link2sd
- Choose APN Settings
- Make system app. 
- Reset phone 
- Run APN Settings and get your settings 
- Reset phone.
I hope that helps...
Sorry for bad English :))

Answer (score -1):

Well it happens to be APN problem, I contacted my network provider and did apn reset and everything works fine.